# regular expression: put $ in [ ]

Tags: regex, perl

```
echo "tests"|perl -pe "s/s[t$]//g"
Unmatched [ in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/s[ <-- HERE 5.020000/ at -e line 1, <> line 1.
```

Can't I put `$` in `[ ]`? Why? Is there any another method to match `t` or `$`?

Comment: Just escape the `$`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice the regular expression in the error message (after removing the marker):

```
m/s[5.020000/
```

This gives us a clue about what is happening. The `$]` was replaced with `5.020000` before the regex was evaluated. Referring to [`man perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Deprecated-and-removed-variables), we can see that `$]` is a special variable:

> The version + patchlevel / 1000 of the Perl interpreter.

To prevent the variable expansion, add some escaping:

```
echo "tests" | perl -pe 's/t[s\$]//g'
```

This will remove `ts` or literal `t$`. If you want the `$` to represent the end of the line (to trim both `test` and `tests`), use:

```
echo -e "tests\ntest" | perl -pe 's/t(s|$)//g'
```

or make the `s` optional:

```
echo -e "tests\ntest" | perl -pe 's/ts?$//g'
```

Comment: @MarkZar, updated answer based on what I think you're trying to do from your other question. Let me know if I've assumed wrongly.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the `$` sign, because it is a special character:

```
echo "tests"|perl -pe "s/s[t\\$]//g"
```

Comment: @MarkZar,Use single quotes instead of double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use `sed` with your expression as is:

```
echo "tests"| sed "s/s[t$]//g"
```